# Java. Moving in a xml with the same tag name as child

Tags: java, xml, tags, element, parent

The problem I have is that I have to work with an xml file the providers of the company I work for sent to me.
This would not be a problem if the xml was well constructed but it is not at all.

```
<catalog>
    <product>
        <ref>4780</ref>
             .
             .
             .
        <arrivals>
            <product>
                <image title="AMARILLO">AMA</image>
                <size>S/T </size>
            </product>
            <product>
                <image title="AZUL">AZUL</image>
                <size>S/T </size>
            </product>
        </arrivals>
    </product>
</catalog>
```

As you can see, the tag `<product>` have all the information of the product but there are more tags named `<product>` to distinguish when there are different colors.
This is the code I use to move in the xml.

```
doc = db.parse("filename.xml");
Element esproducte = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("product").item(0);

NodeList nArrv = esproducte.getElementsByTagName("arrivals");
Element eArrv = (Element) nArrv.item(0);
NodeList eProds = eArrv.getElementsByTagName("product");//THIS THING

for(int l=0; l<eProds.getLength(); l++)
{
Node ln = eProds.item(l);
if (ln.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
{
    Element le = (Element) ln;

    //COLORS / IMAGES / CONFIGS
    NodeList nimgcol = le.getElementsByTagName("image");
    Element eimgcol = (Element) nimgcol.item(0);
    System.out.println("Name of the color " + eimgcol.getTextContent());
}
```

What happens is that the print is reapeated more times it should and I think it's because of the parent `<product>`. I thought it shouldn't happen because where I wrote `//THIS THING` I take into account the fact that `<product>` is set in `<arrivals>`. But it is not working.
What should I modify in the code to move only 2 times in the for and not 3, which is what happen in this case?

**Solution:**

```
NodeList eProds = eArrv.getElementsByTagName("product");//THIS THING
```

to

```
NodeList eProds = eArrv.getChildNodes();//THIS THING
```

And the rest exactly the same. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` give you all Tags with the name "product" that are inside that tag, including those "product" tags for colors.
Try use `getChildNodes` and check the name of the Nodes instead

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly **valid** to have tags inside different parent elements that are named the same, but have different content/meaning, as is the case in your example.

An element whose path is `/catalog/product` is entirely different from an element whose path is `/catalog/product/arrivals/product`. As an example, both *XPath* and *XML Schema* will consider them distinct.

It is only **lazily written code** that cannot distinguish the difference, e.g. by using `getElementsByTagName`, which locates elements anywhere ("all descendants") regardless of the location (path).

When processing the DOM tree, do it in a structured fashion:

- Iterate all child elements (not all descendants) of the root (`catalog`).
- *Depending on strictness, fail if elements are not named `product`.*
- For each element named `product`:

  - Iterate all child elements of the `product` element.
  - Process element by name, e.g. `ref`, `arrivals`.
  - *If strict, fail if element name is unknown.*
  - If element name is `arrivals`:

    - Iterate all child elements of the `arrivals` element.
    - *If strict, fail if elements are not named `product`.*
    - For each element named `product`:

      - Process element by name, e.g. `image`, `size`.
      - *If strict, fail if element name is unknown.*

As you can see, the place in your code that handles an element named `product` inside an element named `catalog` is different from the code that handles an element named `product` inside an element named `arrivals`.

Answer (score 1):

As Andreas mentioned there is nothing invalid about the document and the problem is using getElementsByTagName, which simply scans the entire document for any elements with that tag name, regardless of structure.

You can use XPath to simplify the traversal of specific elements.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XMLParsing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
        String xml = "<catalog>\n" +
                "    <product>\n" +
                "        <ref>4780</ref>\n" +
                "             .\n" +
                "             .\n" +
                "             .\n" +
                "        <arrivals>\n" +
                "            <product>\n" +
                "                <image title=\"AMARILLO\">AMA</image>\n" +
                "                <size>S/T </size>\n" +
                "            </product>\n" +
                "            <product>\n" +
                "                <image title=\"AZUL\">AZUL</image>\n" +
                "                <size>S/T </size>\n" +
                "            </product>\n" +
                "        </arrivals>\n" +
                "    </product>\n" +
                "</catalog>\n";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

        // get all products under "arrivals"
        XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("/catalog/product/arrivals//product");

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node product = nodes.item(i);
            NodeList productChildren = product.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < productChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                Node item = productChildren.item(j);
                if (item instanceof Element) {
                    Element element = (Element) item;
                    switch (element.getTagName()) {
                        case "image":
                            System.out.println("product image title : " + element.getAttribute("title"));
                            break;
                        case "size":
                            System.out.println("product size : " + element.getTextContent());
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you only meant to have a single `/` between `arrivals` and `product`?

Comment: Won't that code iterate all "Arrivals Products" across all "Catalog Products" as a flat list, losing track of which "Arrivals Products" belong to "Catalog Product" with ref=4780, as opposed to "Arrivals Products" belonging to "Catalog Product" with ref=4781 (for example)?